# error with code, use of undeclared type

Tags: swift3

I have this error 
[use of undeclared type "view1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umdI3.png)
what can I do to fix it. here is the code for the error.

```
@IBAction func btnActionShowViewController(_ sender: Any) {

    let view1:UIViewController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: //error is here
"StoryboardIdOfview1") as? view1

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view1, animated: true)

}
```

here is my full code.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  app21
//
//  Created by Jared Evan Miller on 8/14/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Jared Evan Miller. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
// sounds are showed here
let soundFilenames = ["5","8","7","4","6","1","3","2","9"]
var audioPlayers = [AVAudioPlayer]()
// stop button and play from begginning
var lastAudioPlayer = 0
// back to code
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

// set up audio players
   for sound in soundFilenames{
        do {

            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: "wav")!);
            let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:url)

            audioPlayers.append(audioPlayer)
        }
        catch {

            // Catch the error that is thrown
            audioPlayers.append(AVAudioPlayer())


        }
               }

  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.



// IBAction section ( always goes in between the last and second to last bracket } (  IBAction would go here)     }




}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

// Get the audioPlayer that corresponds to the button that they tapped
// middle buttons
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}
// side buttons
@IBAction func buttonTapped2(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let lastPlayer = audioPlayers[lastAudioPlayer]
    lastPlayer.stop();
    lastAudioPlayer = sender.tag;
    lastPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer = audioPlayers[sender.tag]
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    audioPlayer.play()
}
// This Action allows users to stop the audio
// stop audio button
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.stop()
   }
}
```

This is the part where I have a button that has two actions at once and I want the first one to play music and the second one to show another view controller named view1. Thanks.

```
@IBAction func btnActionPlayMusic(_ sender: Any) {


}





@IBAction func btnActionShowViewController(_ sender: Any) {

    let view1:UIViewController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: //error is here
"StoryboardIdOfview1") as? view1

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view1, animated: true)

}





}
```

Comment: You're casting something as a variable to which you assign the returned value... how would this work?

Comment: I just found it online and copied and paste today I don't know the real code

Comment: What I want that code to do is to go to the other view controller that's called view1

Comment: Well the problem is your cast. Remove the as? view1. Thats not needed as the function returns the object type that your variable is of. If anything you should be casting it as UIViewController..

Comment: Can you send me the code I don't know it

Comment: select the view controller you are trying to segue to.  Click on the orange circle at the top of the controller.  In the inspector panel on the right, naviate to the tab I selected in the image that I presented in my answer.  What is specified in custom class?  That is what you must put after as? in your statement.

Comment: ViewController is what it says

Comment: can you please post some sample of your view1 code?

Comment: @IBAction func btnActionShowViewController(_sender: Any) { let view1: UIViewController = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withidentifier:"StoryboardIdOfview1") as? UIViewController                                                           self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view1,animated: true)

Comment: With this code I get an error value of optional type 'UIViewController?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are casting the destinationViewController incorrectly....  as?
 view1 is probably incorrect. Your code:

```
let view1:UIViewController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: //error is here
"StoryboardIdOfview1") as? view1
```

You should be casting like so:

```
let view1:UIViewController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: //error is here
"StoryboardIdOfview1") as! view1UIViewController
```

Where view1UIViewController is you the custom class of the view controller you define in identity inspector as shown below:

[image]

===EDIT=== 
Based on your comment the problem line of code should read:

```
let view1:UIViewController =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: //error is here
"StoryboardIdOfview1") as? UIViewController
```

Comment: I have view1 as the storyboard id

Comment: Also I don't have two view controller.Swift things only one and just to storyboards

Comment: Two storyboards

Comment: That's not enough Jared.  That identifies the target Controller to segue to, but you have to specify its type correctly.  Is view1 simply a UIViewController, or a custom UIViewController.  If it's the latter, you must specify exactly what you have in the image above.  If it is not custom, you don't specify a name, but rather its class type... UIViewController.

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: What is your Messenger account name so we can chat on messenger

Comment: What is your Messenger account name so we can chat on messenger

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: What about your email

Comment: The custom class is ViewController

Comment: See my Edit to the answer I posted.  Try to be precise in the future.  It is not ViewController.  It is UIViewController.  Good luck!